# Oracle OBIEE 12c: Unable to log into analytics

Tags: java-8, obiee

I have successfully installed OBIEE 12c and I can log into em and console. However, the login page for analytics comes up but when I try to log in I get:

Error 500--Internal Server Error
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Looking at the log, I realize that this is the cause:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed IPv6 address at index 8: ldap://[192.168.0.24]:9500

I understand that it is an issue related to jdk 8. Any work around please

Comment: After hustling for so long, I realized that it was an issue associated with the java version. Apparently, the current java version had issues with IPV 6. I deinstalled bi, dropped the repository, removed the java, installed an earlier version, u202. then created repository again before configuring bi again

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue with login into OBIEE 12.2.1.4.0 analytics and xmlpserver and getting an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed IPv6 address at index 8: ldap://[host]:9500
```

Cause: JDK8 update 331+ is handling of URLs more strict than OBIEE "expects".

[Support Doc ID 2865508.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2865508.1) has issue details and solution which helped me fix an error. I've applied [Patch 34065214](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchSearchResults?searchdata=%3Ccontext%20type%3D%22BASIC%22%20search%3D%22%26lt%3BSearch%26gt%3B%26lt%3BFilter%20name%3D%26quot%3Bpatch_number%26quot%3B%20op%3D%26quot%3Bis%26quot%3B%20value%3D%26quot%3B34065214%26quot%3B%2F%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FSearch%26gt%3B%22%2F%3E) from that doc.

Thanks to Martien van den Akker for article [Solving URL protocol exceptions with latest JDK updates](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/solving-url-protocol-exceptions-with-latest-jdk-updates-7c6c85844518).